# Missing elements in Feed data returned by Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Graph API to retrieve Feed data from a number of public Facebook pages and a public Facebook group. The array of data returned by the API occasionally contains Posts with missing data which is visible when the Posts are viewed in Facebook.
I wonder if anyone can shed light on this, and explain whether it is just a glitch in the Graph API, or some sort of permissions issue?

The problem appears to occur with data from the public Facebook Group, and affects Posts which are of [type]=Status under certain conditions. A couple of examples:

1. Posts of [type]=Status where the user has included a link: In this scenario, the Post [message] is present, but the [link] and [picture] elements are missing. The data returned includes the following data - "[caption] => Attachment UnavailableThis attachment may have been removed or the person who shared it may not have permission to share it with you".
   All the [comments] and [likes] data is present and correct.
2. Posts of [type]=Status where the user has posted a photo: In this scenario, the [message] and [picture] elements are missing, but the [comments] and [likes] data is present.

For Posts of [type]=Status with just a simple [message] (no photo or link) the Post data all seems to be returned correctly by the API. Posts of [type]=Link or [type]=Photo are also returned correctly. I don't seem to see any of these problems when retrieving data from the Facebook Pages.

I am using the Facebook PHP SDK to retrieve the data. Currently I am using SDK 4, but I experienced the same problem with the previous version of the PHP SDK. I am making a simple GET call, with an App Session constructed using my App ID and App Secret (no access token).

I'm guessing there is something subtle going on with permissions here (as indicated by the caption message for the first scenario above) but the Group is public, and the missing data can be viewed on the Group page by any Facebook user.
[This question appears to be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285479/posts-in-group-feed-have-unavailable-content) but I have not been able to track down any information about my specific problems, so any suggestions gratefully received!